# Pandasql query of a list or dict of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

Given a set of files - each one of which is read into a distinct `dataframe` - how might a `pandasql` query reference them?

In the following snippet we have a `list` of `dataframes`: but the same question would apply to a `dict`:

```
import pandas as pd
from  pandasql import sqldf
# Read in a set of 10 files each containing columns `id` and `estimate`
dfs = [pd.read_csv('file%d.csv' %d) for d in range(1,10+1)]
sql_res = sqldf("select d2.estimate - d1.estimate \
    from dfs[1] d1 join dfs[2] d2 on d2.id = d1.id", locals())
```

The `dfs[1]` and `dfs[2]` are showing what I'd *like* to do - but are not valid syntax.  Any suggestions on how to structure this kind of problem in a way that `pandasql` can support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell pandasql a list of table names/aliases instead of just passing `locals()`, as per the docstring of `PandasSQL.__call__` (can't find online version of the docs):

```
:param env: Variables environment - a dict mapping table names to pandas dataframes.
```

Note that you must put *all* tables that you want to query there, though.

Here is a small example, using the `PandasSQL` class instead of `sqldf` as recommended in the docstring:

```
import pandasql

sql = pandasql.PandaSQL()


data_frames = [
    pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]}),
    pd.DataFrame({'b': [1,4,5]})
]

# create aliases for your dataframes
env = {'t%d' % (i + 1): df for i, df in enumerate(data_frames)}

# tell pandasql to use the aliases
print(sql('select t1.* from t1 join t2 on t1.a = t2.b', env=env))
```

Comment: nice one - i'm pretty sure this is going to be the best approach. btw I had been looking into using `exec` to make assignments like this but that does not work for `locals()` only `globals()`. This avoids that whole mess